# Parametric Pothole

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, parametric

> Find a Cartesian equation for the parametric equations:
>   $$\begin{align}
> x&=\cos(t) \\
> y&=7\sin(t)
> \end{align}$$

My attempt to solve the question was as follows: if we take the $\cos^{-1}(x)$ we can figure out what our $t$ was (we restrict the $t$ to $0\le t\le\pi$). Now we simply take the sine of this angle. Using the Pythagorean theorem, we can simplify $y=7\sin(\cos^{-1}(t))$ to $y=7\sqrt{1-x^2}$. On the other hand, the answer key says that the correct solution is $49x^2+y^2=49$.

I can see how they got to this answer (multiply first equation by $7$, square, and then add), but I don't understand two things. Why is my answer incorrect? Also, I understand that we can manipulate these equations and get the right answer, but what is really going on here (i.e. why do $x=\cos(t)$ and $y=7\sin(t)$ pop out the equation for an ellipse)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think your answer is incorect? $$ 49x^2+y^2 = 49 \Rightarrow y = \sqrt{49(1-x^2)} = 7 \sqrt{1-x^2}$$ .

Comment: ahf;adslkjf;lasdkfj;laskjds;lkfj;alsfkdj???!??!!?!??!

Comment: @denklo can you explain the answer through intuition too though?

Comment: Your answer only covers half of the curve—you’ve added a restriction on $t$ that didn’t exist in the original parameterization.

Comment: @Dude156 i'm not sure which sort of explanation you expect.

Comment: @Dude156 _why does x=cos(t) and y=7sin(t) pop out the equation for an ellipse_ An ellipse is a circle stretched along some direction. In our case along $y$ by factor 7. The parametrization of a circle is $x = \cos(t)$ $y = \sin(t)$.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes, that helped me visualize it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is not completely incorrect, it is just incomplete. As you can see, a square root has two solutions to it: the positive and negative ones. You happened to express the positive one only (in this case, you only expressed the equation that describes the opper half of the curve). This is also due to the fact that you used a specific range for $t$, but it is not the only one you can use. In the end, it should look something like this:
$$ y= \pm 7\sqrt{1 - x^2} $$
Which means, of course, that the points $(y, x)$ of the curve satisfy:
$$ y= 7\sqrt{1 - x^2} \quad \text{or} \quad y= - 7\sqrt{1 - x^2}$$
To turn it into a compact form, you can square both sides of one of the equations and rearrange.
$$ y^2 + 49x^2 = 49 $$

Answer (score 1):

If $ x = \cos(t)$ and $y = 7* \sin(t)$, then

$$49 x^2+y^2=49 \cos^2(t)+49 \sin^2(t)=49(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t))=49,$$

since $\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1$.